# function passed with argument as "& $x" outputs a value rather than error see the code below

Tags: php, pass-by-reference

Below is the code which outputs "15", why?

```
function zz(&$x){

$x = $x + 5;

}

$x = 10;

zz($x);
echo $x;
```

Please explain

Comment: looks like a question from Zend's mock exams.

Comment: MAy b But I was asked in the Interview which I answered wrong.. hence thought placing it here..

Comment: *(related)* [What does that symbol mean in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are passing the value as argument is not direct value of the variable but its passing By reference, so its giving you 15 as a output.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Works as designed. By using `&` you pass `$x` by reference, meaning that anything the function does to the variable, will be done to the original `$x` that is set to `10`.

If you used

```
function zz($x)
```

the original `$x` would stay at `10`, because only the variable *value* is passed to the function.

Answer (score 2):

Because the function signature defines that the value passed to the function should be passed by reference.

If you don't know what that means, I suggest to read [this paragraph on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pass_by_reference#Call_by_reference).

Answer (score 1):

Adding a & means you are passing the $x variable by reference.  The value outside is changed within the function, instead of a copy within the function being changed.

Answer (score 1):

`$x` inside the function is a reference to the same value as `$x` outside your function.

When a function accepts a parameter with a "&", it's value is not copied into the new variable created inside the function's scope, but is a reference to the same value as the argument that was given.

See [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php).

Answer (score 1):

Using & Ampersand: Passing by Reference mets the purpose in the function.

Its simply alter the original variable and return it again to the same variable name with its new value assigned.